# Easiest way to deploy web app to Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to deploy my first servlet to my server. There are, of course, many tutorials online. But most of them are very detailed and complicated, and I only need to deploy a few simply servlets to this server.

I found what I think to be the shortest method of deployment: [Deployment on Tomcat Startup](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deployment_on_Tomcat_startup). I moved my .WAR file (`FirstProject.war`) into `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps` folder, but when trying to access it (`ServerIP/FirstProject`) I get the "*The requested resource is not available*." error.

Is there anything I forgot in the process of deployment?

I know that `deployOnStartup` has to be set to `true`, but I didn't change anything with the server's hosts, so the current host is `localhost`. I didn't change its settings, so `deployOnStartup` should be `true` (It's said that `true` is the default).

What am I missing?

Comment: What port are you giving? Can you post your tomcat config file?

Comment: Do you have an index.html file declared?  If not, what do you expect?  Is Tomcat still listening on its default port, 8080?

Comment: Most likely there is an issue with your servlet mapping.

Comment: It was a problem with the mapping, found the problem using the web application manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using easiest way but I don't know what you are missing. Here what I would suggest is run your server and access through localhost:8080 then click manage app then enter username and password then you can deploy your war.
If you have any query post command.

Comment: Thanks, the web application manager gave me more information of my problem (Which was the wrong servlet mapping)

Answer (score 0):

Even  i used to face this problem while deploying my first web application on Jboss and Apache ..

Even though your code is working properly with all  your servlet mappings and paths using in  your content files ...some times they kick back in  real time environment ..So we have to  know the proper deployment folder structure and accordingly we have to change our paths in the code

what i am concluding is check the below lines of code

```
   Examples, assuming root is http://foo.com/site/

Absolute path, no matter where we are on the site

/foo.html

will refer to http://foo.com/site/foo.html

Relative path, assuming the containing link is located in http://foo.com/site/part1/bar.html

../part2/quux.html

will refer to http://foo.com/site/part2/quux.html

or

part2/blue.html

will refer to http://foo.com/site/part1/part2/blue.html
```